# Kendo grid paging not initialized properly (NaN - NaN)

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid

Here is the running example
http://dojo.telerik.com/exok/12

It's basically Kendo grid with Angular. Datasource as ObservableArray (this works better than just DataSource).
The problem is that current page is not set, and the footer displays NaN - NaN of 3 items.
[image]

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set the pagesize for the grid

dataSource:
        {
          data: $scope.people,
          pageSize: 10
        },

Answer (score 2):

I finished by using the DataSource. ObservableArray doesn't have the pageSize property, and pageable object is not passing the pageSize to the grid. 
This answer helped me
[Changing Angular model to update Kendo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031735/changing-angular-model-to-update-kendo/22997017#answer-22997017)

Answer (score 0):

you should return total records number from server :

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
              read: {
                    url: "..."
                }
     },
    schema: {
         total: function(response){ return response.total;}               
    },
    pageSize: 5,
    serverPaging: true,
    serverSorting: true
};

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
datasource: dataSource,
pageSize: true,
});
```