# How to get AngularJS and KendoUI working in harmony?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, kendo-ui, odata

In stages, I setup my .Net MVC solution and ensured both Angular JS and KendoUI are working independently.

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['kendo.directives']);
```

and in my controller, I have the following defined:

```
app.controller('contentTypesController', ['$scope', '$log', 'contentTypesRepository',
    function ($scope, $log, contentTypesRepository) {

        var a = {};

        $scope.status;
        $scope.contentTypes;

        $scope.contentTypeOptions;

        // for testing purposes, but not used - used for navigation properties
        $scope.users;

        getContentTypes();

        function getContentTypes() {
            // call the data repository
            contentTypesRepository.getList()
                .success(function (contentTypes) {
                    //console.log(contentTypes.value[0].Description);
                    //$log.log(contentTypes.value[0].Description)
                    $scope.contentTypes = contentTypes;
                    $scope.contentTypeOptions = {
                        dataSource: {
                            data: contentTypes
                        },
                        dataTextField: "Description",
                        dataValueField: "ContentTypeId",
                        optionLabel: "Select a Content Type"
                    };

                })
                .error(function (error) {
                    $scope.status = 'Unable to load data: ' + error.message;
                });
        }

        $scope.updateContentTypes = function (id) {
            var contentType;

            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.contentTypes.length; i++) {
                var currentType = $scope.contentTypes[i];
                if (currentType.ID === id) {
                    contentType = currentType;
                    break;
                }
            }
        };

        $scope.insertContentType = function () {
            // get contentType description from the client
            var contentType = { 'Description': $scope.newContentType };

            contentTypesRepository.insert(contentType)
                .success(function () {
                    $scope.status = 'Added new content type.  Refreshing list.';
                    // add the new content type to the client-side collection
                    $scope.contentTypes.value.push(
                                    { 'Description': $scope.newContentType }
                                );
                    $scope.newContentType = "";
                })
                .error(function (error) {
                    $scope.status = 'Unable to insert new content type: ' + error.message;
                });
        };

        $scope.deleteContentType = function(id) {
            contentTypesRepository.remove(id)
                .success(function () {
                    $scope.status = 'Deleted content type.  Refreshing list.';
                    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.contentTypes.length; i++) {
                        var contentType = $scope.contentTypes[i];
                        if (contentType.ID === id) {
                            // remove the content type from the client-side collection
                            $scope.contentTypes.splice(i, 1);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    // navigation properties = null
                    // $scope.xxxx = null;
                })
                .error(function (error) {
                    $scope.status = 'Unable to delete content type: ' + error.message;
                });
        };

        // get some navigation property
        //$scope.getCustomerOrders = function (id) {
        //    dataFactory.getOrders(id)
        //    .success(function (orders) {
        //        $scope.status = 'Retrieved orders!';
        //        $scope.orders = orders;
        //    })
        //    .error(function (error) {
        //        $scope.status = 'Error retrieving customers! ' + error.message;
        //    });
        //};


        $scope.addContentType = function () {

            //return $scope.newContentType.$save();
            $scope.contentTypes.value.push(
                { 'Description': $scope.newContentType }
            );
            $scope.newContentType = "";
        }
```

In following the Angluar/Kendo examples [here](http://kendo-labs.github.io/angular-kendo/#/), I added code related to `$scope.contentTypeOptions`.

In my view:

```
<select kendo-drop-down-list k-options="contentTypeOptions"></select>
```

Which displays a dropdown, but no data.

I am able to view the data in a `ng-repeater`:

```
                        <ul>
                            <li ng-repeat="contentType in contentTypes.value">
                                {{ contentType.Description }}
                            </li>
                        </ul>
```

And the raw data by  `{{ contentTypeOptions }}`.

Since the repeater uses contentTypes.value, I tried this as well in

```
                    $scope.contentTypeOptions = {
                        dataSource: {
                            data: contentTypes.value  // tried both contentTypes and contentTypes.value
                        },
                        dataTextField: "Description",
                        dataValueField: "ContentTypeId",
                        optionLabel: "Select a Content Type"
                    };
```

... which is based on the JSON data:

[image]

Ultimately, I would like to get all the CRUD hooked up for a grid (which I have done in the past with OData, but now adding AngularJS to the mix) and thought simply displaying the data in an Angular/Kendo mix would be a good start.  I'm hoping that after getting this pinned down the rest will be simple, and appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I would ask this in the github angular-kendo repo, but even then there doesn't seem to be much focus on that project from kendo ui. I've managed to hook up a pretty decent kendo grid and multiselect setup with angular, but not any other kendo widgets.

Comment: what is the type of contentTypes.value?

Comment: @LarsHöppner - `value` is a collection/array containing the content type objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a bit confusing since methods like `$scope.updateContentTypes` treat `$scope.contentTypes` as an array, but at the same time `contentTypes` appears to be an object with a property `value` which is an array.

One thing to be aware of is that Kendo UI widgets will convert your array to a Kendo DataSource internally. This means that changes you make to `$scope.contentTypes` won't affect the items in your data source in `$scope.contentTypeOptions`.

Another issue is that there is no full two-way binding between widgets and the data source in angular-kendo, and until recently, the data source wouldn't update at all unless you specifically declared it as a DataSource. There have been some improvements lately, although it's still not fully integrated, as far as I can see.
(you can try creating a deep watch on the data yourself, but that may create performance problems; see [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20983456/2001735) post here).

Your dropdown doesn't show the data because you replace `$scope.contentTypeOptions` after creating the widget, and there is no `$watch` on that property that would update the widget with these options. 
You can either create a DataSource explicitly and update that with:

```
$scope.contentTypeOptions.dataSource.data(contentType.value);
```

or you can use the attribute:

```
k-data-source="contentTypes"
```

which will create a `$watch` on `$scope.contentTypes`, so when you replace it, the widget will update as well.

Maybe this basic (although admittedly a bit messy) [example](http://jsbin.com/EyuJOTIR/6/edit) will help you somewhat (I set up the 2nd dropdown in the same way you did; the "change" button updates the data source).

Comment: Ok, so I got your example working - thank you.  However, I am using a factory that populates the data in `getContentTypes()` (thorugh an OData provider, which is why you see `.value` in there).  When I try to do that, in the `.success(function (contentTypes) {}` this doesn't work.  I created something similar here http://jsbin.com/EdoyUxU/2/edit which works but I haven't done it similar to my example above.

Comment: where your data comes from shouldn't make a difference as long as you have an array with the required elements; I'd need to see a non-working example to help you further

Comment: I am surprised no vote ups on this answer. This absolutely works, for binding a kendo multi-select with async resource data.

Comment: The example provided does not work.  Is there an updated example?

Comment: @Bloodhound AngularJS support is now part of Kendo UI, so the demo is very outdated; you can find documentation for Kendo UI and AngularJS here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/the-grid-widget

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the Angular Kendo bindings from Kendo labs.

Here is a an article with live demo and full source code:

http://blog.longle.io/2014/05/01/angularjs-kendo-ui-using-angular-kendo-with-asp-net-mvc-5-web-api-odata