# How to setup CURD with KendoUI grid for use with Kendo-Angular and an Angular OData factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-grid

In a previous project, where I was not using Angular, I setup a `Kendo.DataSource` that used an OData endpoint as follows:

```
            var userDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            type: "odata",
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/api/Users?$filter=USERGROUPS/any(usergroup: usergroup/ID eq '" + groupData.ID + "')",           // only need to expand users for the selected group
                    dataType: "json",                                // the default result type is JSONP, but WebAPI does not support JSONP
                },
                update: {
                    url: function (data) {
                        // TODO: write UpdateEntity controller method
                        return "/api/Users(" + groupData.ID + ")";
                    },
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                destroy: {
                    url: function (data) {
                        // TODO: write Delete controller method
                        return "/api/Users(" + groupData.ID + ")";
                    },
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                parameterMap: function (options, type) {
                    // this is optional - if we need to remove any parameters (due to partial OData support in WebAPI
                    var parameterMap = kendo.data.transports.odata.parameterMap(options);
                    return parameterMap;
                }
            },
```

Now, introducing AngularJS into the mix, I would like to know how to define the `read`, `update` and `destroy` events using my AngularJS factory, where there is no URL.

My factory contracts are setup as follows:

- `contentTypesFactory.getList()`
- `contentTypesFactory.insert(contentType)`
- `contentTypesFacotry.remove(id)`

The first problem I see with `.getList()` is that it doesn't take in any query string parameters, like `$orderby` and `$inlinecount=allpages` which I need for use with the KendoUI Grid.  It is inside this factory that the URL is defined, then calls an abstract factory (see below).

I need to somehow pass in the URL and the entity name to my factory from the `kendo.datasource` url: function (remember, that the grid control will append whatever OData querystring parameters are required).

So, how I would setup the factory to output the data expected for each of the CRUD events.

Data source definition:

```
$scope.contentTypesDataSource = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    type: "odata",
    transport: {
        read: {
            //url: "/api/UserGroups?$orderby=GROUPNAME",
            url: '/odata/ContentTypes',
            //function (data) {
                // pass in the URL to the abstract factory                     
            //},
            dataType: "json"                                // the default result type is JSONP, but WebAPI does not support JSONP
        },
        update: {

        },
        destroy: {

        },
        parameterMap: function (options, type) { ...
```

Abstract repository:

```
app.factory('abstractRepository', [function () {

    // we will inject the $http service as repository service
    // however we can later refactor this to use another service
    function abstractRepository(repositoryService, whichEntity, odataUrlBase) {
        //this.http = $http;
        this.http = repositoryService;
        this.whichEntity = whichEntity;
        this.odataUrlBase = odataUrlBase;
        this.route;
    }

    abstractRepository.prototype = {
        getList: function () {
            return this.http.get(this.odataUrlBase);
        },
        get: function (id) {
            return this.http.get(this.odataUrlBase + '/' + id);
        },
        insert: function (entity) {
            return this.http.post(this.odataUrlBase, entity);
        },
        update: function (entity) {
            return this.http.put(this.odataUrlBase + '/' + entity.ID, this.whichEntity);
        },
        remove: function (id) {
            return this.http.delete(this.odataUrlBase + '/' + id);
        }
    };

    abstractRepository.extend = function (repository) {
        repository.prototype = Object.create(abstractRepository.prototype);
        repository.prototype.constructor = repository;

    }

    return abstractRepository;

}]);
```

ContentTypesFactory.js:

```
// each function returns a promise that can be wired up to callback functions by the caller
// the object returned from the factory is a singleton and can be reused by different controllers
app.factory('contentTypesRepository', ['$http', 'abstractRepository', function ($http, abstractRepository) {

    var odataUrlBase = '/odata/ContentTypes'
    var whichEntity = 'ContentTypes';

    function contentTypesRepository() {
        abstractRepository.call(this, $http, whichEntity, odataUrlBase);
    }

    abstractRepository.extend(contentTypesRepository);

    return new contentTypesRepository();

}]);
```

After looking at [kendo-examples-asp-net](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-examples-asp-net), I'm thinking that I should do away with the `ContentTypesFactory` and the abstract repository and call the OData endpoint directly - of course this is relatively easy.

However, my initial reason for creating an Angular repository was so that I could do JS unit testing on the data functions.  To retain this feature, how can I call the abstract repository directly from the data source functions, and this the recommended way of accomplishing this?